# What are some chemical reactions that failed to scale up?

Tags: chemical-engineering

Also, what happened to the reactions after they failed to scale up? Were they commercialized? Sold?

Comment: do you mean a chemical reaction that doesn't work when you increase quantities?  Or that had a commercial application that didn't work at high volume?

Comment: Chemical reactions that dont work at scale: increased quantities.

Answer (score 1):

'Failed to scale up' can be a commercial thing as much as technological, will comment on that.

Typically for anything novel, companies will file some but not all patents before they have commercialized the process, and/or will try to "own" the IP by way of trade secret, getting the the key personnel under NDA's. If the project would succeed, the bulk of the IP would actually come later with the details of implementing the process/product at scale, but at the same time as money is first being discussed, it is effectively mandatory to have at least minimal patent protection.

If a project was developed in academia going into a startup company, a  "failed scale-up" will often be of most interest to an established company, whose technology is under threat of being replaced by the new invention. They might be the main early-stage investor. If it was developed in-house a large company already profiting from a competing technology, the result is the same.

Once owned by an established company, they might sit on the IP for the technology in question while waiting for whatever complementary tech is needed to actually make it economical. Often this wait goes all the way to the expiration of the patents, and the pieces left behind are put together by a competing company, who can do nothing until this time has passed, without the help of the original inventors.

The interesting alternative, is if the invention was developed or acquired by an established company (i.e. with financial resources), with the intention of taking out a competitor, rather for their own use. Then they might go out of their way to allow collaboration to bring it to market, even if they can't do it on their own.

Comment: You make it sound like a matter of willpower to scale up.

Comment: @Dale - Oh that wasn't my intention. More like, "willpower" -- rendered into the language of a business, meaning actually writing the checks for people and capital -- is a key ingredient. So is organizational ability, which is the stumbling block I find most baffling. And so is the technical part.